# How to update localy a Yesod monad

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using Yesod and need to modify temporarily `approot` so that `renderUrl` generate local routes (ie starting with `/`) instead of global ones (include the host).

One way to do so would be to override `approot` with `ApprootRelative` and call `renderUrl`. However, I'm inside a [Yesod monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.26/docs/Yesod-Core.html) monad, so I'm not sure how can get a yesod "object", modify it's `approot` and call `renderUrl` to it.

Comment: There's not any straightforward way to do this. You'd have to get at the internals of the `HandlerT` value and then replace its rendering function. It's probably easier to do something like `Data.Text.replace` on the domain name (though please don't do something that brash...).

Comment: I found a workaround using `renderRoute`, it's just annoying to not be able modify temporarily the app settings.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer?